# Find supX, infX, maxX and minX on a set

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find sup X, inf X, max X and min X when $X = \left\{ \frac{n}{n + m^2 + 1}: n,m \in \mathbb{N}\right\} $ Without using limits.

All i could find is that the upper limit must be lower than 1 and lower limit higher than 0. But I think I could prove this and find a better answer, but I am stuck, because I have not done an excercise with two values m and n and I am not sure how to approach and explain this.

Comment: Is $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ in your context? (If not, then the max and min won't exist, i.e., the sup and inf will not be achieved). (Also "{" and "}" are special characters in $\LaTeX$, use "\{" and "\}" to get braces that you can see - I've fixed it for you and added another fancy bit of formatting that makes the braces grow to the right size.)

Comment: No $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. But I how could I prove what is the sup and inf?

Comment: Just use your intuition to see how to make the formula $n/(n + m + 1)$ as small and as large as possible.

Comment: The infimum should be "easy" to find: you can make the denominator arbitrarily large for fixed $n$ so you can get arbitrarily close to $0$. For the supremum, try setting $m=0$ and let $n$ get bigger, what does that approach and why should it be the supremum?

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about **infimum** first ,

Here, we want to prove that $0$ is the infimum of the given set $X$

Obviously, $\dfrac{n}{n+m^2+1}>0$ , $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. So $0$ is in the set o lower bounds of $X$.

Now, if we can show that in every nbhd of $0$ there exist at least one member of the set $X$ then we are done !

Now, for small $\epsilon >0$ , there exist a positive  integer $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{m^2+2}=x (say)<\epsilon $.

Then, $x=\dfrac{1}{m^2+2} \in X$ for $n=1$ and also $x\in (0-\epsilon,0+\epsilon)$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.

Q.E.D.

Since, the set $X$ can never achieve this value so it does not have minimum.

Now, for **supremum**,

We, we are going to prove that $1$ is the supremum of this set $X$.

First, we show that 1 is in the set of upper bound of $X$.

Suppose, we can find such element $x\in X$ such that $x>1$,

i.e., $$ x=\dfrac{n}{n+m^2+1} >1$$

$$ \Rightarrow n > n+m^2+1$$
A contradiction, as $m\in \mathbb{N}$. So, $1$ is the upper bound of the given set $X$.

Now, we show that in every nbhd of $1$, there is at least one element of set $X$.

Take $m=1$ then we have $\dfrac{n}{n+2}\in X$ , $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$,

Now, take any $\epsilon >0$, then we can write $$ \dfrac{n+2-2}{n+2}=1- \dfrac{2}{n+2} \in X$$

Since, by Archimedean property there exist $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{2}{n+2}< \epsilon$.  So we have
$$ 1-\epsilon < 1-\dfrac{2}{n'+2}<1+\epsilon$$

So we have shown that in every nbhd of $1$ there is at least one element of the set $X$.

Obviously, this set does not contain it's supremum so it can not have any maximum.

That Concludes the proof.